# Traer datos del usuario que atendió el ticket

Tags: codeigniter, mariadb

Estoy intentando obtener los nombres y el apellido paterno del usuario (id_usuario_atendio) que atendió el ticket. El la tabla tickets tengo únicamente 2 tickets lo cuales quiero obtener. Ya tengo la consulta casi terminada, pero cuando pongo un nuevo join apuntando a la tabla de usuarios ($this->db->join('usuarios as ua', 't.id_usuario_atendio = ua.id_usuario'); ) únicamente me esta trayendo un registro, pero cuando quito la condición y los atributos (ua.nombres AS nom_atendio, ua.a_paterno AS ap_atendio) la consulta ya me trae los dos registros y el id del usuario que atendió el ticket, pero no necesito el id, sino los datos antes mencionados.

Les anexo las tablas y la consulta.

> Consulta

```
$this->db->select('t.*, u.nombres AS nom_creacion, u.a_paterno AS ap_creacion, tf.nombre AS riesgo, tt.nombre AS area, ua.nombres AS nom_atendio, ua.a_paterno AS ap_atendio');
            $this->db->from('tickets as t');
            $this->db->join('usuarios as u', 'u.id_usuario = t.id_usuario');
            $this->db->join('tickets_frecuentes as tf', 'tf.id_ticket_frecuente = t.id_ticket_frecuente');
            $this->db->join('tipo_tickets as tt', 'tt.id_tipo_ticket = t.id_tipo_ticket');
            $this->db->join('usuarios as ua', 't.id_usuario_atendio = ua.id_usuario');
            $this->db->where('t.estatus', 1);

            return $this->db->get()->result();
```

> Resultado (unicamnete me tra1 registro y falta 1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Consulta modificada

```
$this->db->select('t.*, u.nombres AS nom_creacion, u.a_paterno AS ap_creacion, tf.nombre AS riesgo, tt.nombre AS area');
            $this->db->from('tickets as t');
            $this->db->join('usuarios as u', 'u.id_usuario = t.id_usuario');
            $this->db->join('tickets_frecuentes as tf', 'tf.id_ticket_frecuente = t.id_ticket_frecuente');
            $this->db->join('tipo_tickets as tt', 'tt.id_tipo_ticket = t.id_tipo_ticket');
            $this->db->where('t.estatus', 1);

            return $this->db->get()->result();
```

> Resultado (aquí si obtengo los 2 registros, pero no los datos del
> usuario que atendió el ticket)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tabla tickets

```
MariaDB [intranet_ucq]> select *from tickets;
+-----------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id_ticket | id_usuario_atendio | id_usuario_cerro | id_usuario_reasignado | solicitud | comentario | estatus | fecha_alta          | fecha_fin           | fecha_cambio        | id_usuario | id_tipo_ticket | id_ticket_estatus | id_ticket_frecuente |
+-----------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|         1 |                  1 |                1 |                     0 | hola      | hola2      |       1 | 2020-10-22 14:00:00 | 2020-10-22 14:00:00 | 2020-10-22 14:00:00 |          1 |              1 |                 1 |                   1 |
|         2 |                  0 |                0 |                     0 | PRUEBA    |            |       1 | 2020-10-23 12:16:23 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |          1 |              1 |                 3 |                   1 |
+-----------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

> Tabla usuarios

```
MariaDB [intranet_ucq]> select *from usuarios;
+------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+
| id_usuario | nombres          | a_paterno | a_materno | email                 | password                         | foto                                                                   | ultimo_login        | fecha_alta          | tipo_usuario_id_tipo_usuario | direcciones_id_direccion |
+------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+
|          1 | Francisco Javier | Ferruzca  | Rojas     | javier_fr@outlook.com | 32a346820d1792eb66d8fb834539d048 | files/admin_photos/96149979_3759051517503082_8847104284358082560_o.jpg | 2038-01-19 03:14:07 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07 |                            4 |                        1 |
+------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar a terminar la consulta.

Saludos y bonita tarde.

Comment: No termino de entender ¿cómo se vinculan las entidades?, es que no lo noto en las tablas

Comment: @Javier fr No te hace falta una tabla que sea del personal que atiende para que puedas hacer el Join a ese dato  ?

Comment: En el atributo id_usuario_atendio  va el id del usuario que atendió el ticket, si no lo han atendido traera 0 de lo contrario el id del usuario y es ahí donde me atore ya que no puedo traer los datos de ese usuario de la tabla usuarios.

Comment: @Cesarin esa podría ser una solución

Comment: Creo que estas utilizando alias, lo que tienes que hacer en el JOIN es empatar las tablas con sus id de referencia en este particular caso el 1.  Luego en el Select pedir que te muestre los datos de ese empate de la tabla usuarios por nombre y apellidos.

Comment: Un ejemplo por favor

Comment: @Javierfr Le deje un ejemplo espero le sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una consulta que actualmente utilizo, la edite para borrar todos los elementos que consulto, solo dejo dos valores consultados directo de la tabla patrimonial bienes, luego hago un INNER JOIN donde se hace el cruce entre dos tablas a través de sus respectivos ID  coincidentes en este caso:entre la tabla bienes Numero_Empleado y la tabla donde se almacena al personal (600 registros aprox) con su respectivo campo numero_empleado, esto hace que en el "SELECT" ubique en la tabla plantilla los valores que estas tratando de recuperar en este caso, hace una concatenacion y obtiene el nombre en una linea por ejemplo : " LUIS SANCHEZ ROBLES"   En tu caso tendrías que casar el id_usuario_atendio y id_usuario.

```html
 $consulta = "SELECT
                    patrimonial.bienes.Id_Bien AS ID_BIEN,
                    patrimonial.bienes.Numero_Empleado AS NUMERO_EMPLEADO,
                    CONCAT(plantilla.personal.plantilla.nombre,' ', plantilla_personal.plantilla.apellido1,' ', plantilla_personal.plantilla.apellido2) AS NOMBRE,
                    
                    FROM patrimonial.bienes
                    INNER JOIN plantilla_personal.plantilla ON patrimonial.bienes.Numero_Empleado = plantilla_personal.plantilla.numero_empleado
        //echo $consulta;
        //exit();
```

Una disculpa por no haber puesto este ejemplo ayer, me ocupe en un revisión de un proyecto y me desocupe ya algo tarde, espero todavía te sirva.